# Stack :push then pop and push again to other stacker

Tags: c, stack

I have a "Truck" and a "Stacker" both using stack.  The user is able to allocate the size of the truck(i have used malloc) and the stacker size with be a fixed size of 5.
I am able to push values to the Truck, but how do I pop the top of the truck and push it into the Stacker?

```
struct box
{
    int item;
    int bin;
    int top;
}*boxs,*stacker;

int i;
int num;
int topt = -1;
int tops = -1;

void main()
{
    void truck();
    void display();
    int op;//option
    char ch;//choice

    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("\n Stack:-");
        printf("\n\n 1.<Insert>");
        printf("\n 2.<Display>");
        printf("\n\n Option: ");

        scanf("%d", &op);fflush(stdin);

        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:truck();break;
            case 2:display();break;
            default:printf("\n Invalid Choice!!!");break;

        } printf("\n\n\n Continue?(Y/N): ");

        scanf("%c", &ch);    fflush(stdin);
    }while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');
    return;
}

void truck()
{
    struct box e;
    int a,temp;


    printf("Enter Number of Boxes to unload from the Truck: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    boxs= (struct box*)malloc(sizeof (struct box));
    temp=num;
    /*tempt->tops=copy-1;*/

    for(a=0; a<num;a++)
    {
        topt++;
        temp--;
        /*tempt[copy-a].tops--;*/
        printf("\n1. Enter Item ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.item);
        boxs[a].item=e.item;fflush(stdin);
        /*tempt[copy-a].item=e.item;*/


        printf("\n2. Enter Bin ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.bin);
        boxs[a].bin=e.bin;fflush(stdin);
        //tempt[copy-a].bin=e.bin;
    }
    stackers();
}

void display()
{
    for(i=0;i<=topt;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d",boxs[i].item);
        printf("\n%d",boxs[i].bin);
    }
}


void stackers()
{
}
```

Comment: Start by filling in something between `{` and `}`. You already pushed your items on your truck. Work it out to to it backwards from the truck to the stacks. And I *strongly* suggest you take this to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), as there are quite a number of things wrong in this code *without* adding more.

Comment: Does this even work as it is? The code has memory leaks all over it. `truck()`  leaks away memory every time it is called because it always assigns to `boxs`. And you only allocate space for one item, yet you access `boxs[a]` with `a > 0`. Fix your code first.

Comment: move your `malloc` in main so it allocate one time.

Comment: It is not fully working. for now i can only add those to the Truck but i can't add to the stacker